# How to fix non-responsive Ubuntu system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, freeze

I use Ubuntu. Sometimes, the system does not have any response with mouse and keyboard. Is there any way to solve this problem except hitting the reset button on the machine?

Comment: that's a tough question because you're not giving us much to go on... if it were me i would CTRL+ALT+F[1..6], login, and kill some processes. but i almost always *know* what's making my machine unresponsive, whereas you don't. and additionally, sometimes i write programs that i know are *going* to make it unresponsive, because i want the program's output.

Comment: Are you sure the system gets unresponsive, or is the system still working but the input devices stop functioning?

Comment: Related (on [ubuntu.se]): [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Comment: This happened to me a few times. I was all set to hard reset, but just pressing the power button once unfroze the system. No idea what was going on but it did unfreeze.

Comment: In my case, it becomes completely unresponsive. Even numluck or capslock keyboard light doesn't toggle. None of the below works. Only option is to press reboot. Ubuntu 20.04 fully updated. Last entry in syslog has to do with canonical-livepatch.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you want a way to reboot, without saving open documents, but without hitting the reset button, then there are ways that are less likely to cause data loss. First, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. That should bring you to a [virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console), as [ixtmixilix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1389/ixtmixilix) said. Once you're in a virtual console, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> will shut down and reboot the machine.

[If that technique doesn't work, there's always <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#Uses).

As for fixing the problem without rebooting, without more information about what is going on, it would be difficult to give a good answer. If you could describe the circumstances under which this occurs (the best way to do that is to **edit your question** to add the information), then that may help people to give good answers. The other thing to consider is that, if your computer is becoming unresponsive--especially if it takes more than a a few seconds for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to bring up a virtual console--then you almost certainly have a bug, and by [reporting it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) you can both help the community and maybe get an answer.

### GUI Glitches Causing Unresponsive WM or X11/Wayland

This might be happening due to an interaction between an application and a *window manager*--or the X11 server or Wayland. A sign that this is the nature of the problem is if an application stops responding and prevents you from entering input with the keyboard or mouse to other application windows. (No application *should* be able to do this; some GUI component must have a bug in it for this to occur.) If that's what's happening, then you can kill the offending process in a virtual console (as [ixtmixilix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1389/ixtmixilix) alluded to):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
2. Log in. You won't see anything as you enter your password. [That's normal.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password)
3. Use a utility like [`ps`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ps.1.html) to figure out the offending program's process name. Sometimes this is easy in Ubuntu, and other times it isn't. For example, the name of an Archive Manager process is `file-roller`. If you have trouble figuring it out, you can usually find the information online without too much trouble (or if you can't, you can post a question about it).

   You can pipe `ps`'s output to [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/grep.1.html) to narrow things down. Suppose it was Archive Manager that was causing the problem. Then you could run:

   ```
    ps x | grep file-roller
   ```

   You'll see an entry for your own `grep` command, plus an entry for `file-roller`.
4. Attempt to kill the offending process with [`SIGTERM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTERM). This gives it the chance to do last-minute cleanup like flushing file buffers, signaling to remote servers that it is about to disconnect (for protocols that do that), and releasing other sorts of resources. To do this, use the [`kill`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/kill.1.html) command:

   ```
   kill PID
   ```

   where **`PID`** is the [process ID number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_ID) of the process you want to kill, obtained from running `ps` in step 3.
5. `SIGTERM` is a way to firmly ask a process to quit. The process can ignore that signal, and will do so when malfunctioning under certain circumstances. So you should check to see that it worked. If it didn't, kill it with [`SIGKILL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGKILL), which it cannot ignore, and which always works except in the rare case where the process is in [uninterruptible sleep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_sleep#Uninterruptible_sleep) (or if it is not really running, but is rather a [zombie process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process)).

   You can both check to see if the process is still running, and kill it with `SIGKILL` if it is, with just one command:

   ```
   kill -KILL PID
   ```

   If you get a message like `kill: (PID) - No such process`, you know killing it with `SIGTERM` worked. If you get no output, you know `SIGTERM` didn't work. In that case, `SIGKILL` probably did, but it's worth checking by running it again. (Press the up arrow key to bring up previous commands, for ease of typing.)
6. In rare instances for your own processes, or always with processes belonging to `root` or another user besides yourself, you must kill the process as `root`. To do that, prepend `sudo`  (including the trailing space) before the above `kill` commands. If the above commands don't work or you're told you don't have the necessary access to kill the process, try it as `root` with `sudo`.

(By the way, `kill -KILL` is the same as the widely popular `kill -9`. I recommend `kill -KILL` because `SIGKILL` is not guaranteed to have `9` as its signal number on all platforms. It works on x86, but that doesn't mean it will necessarily work everywhere. In this way, `kill -KILL` is more likely to successfully end the process than `kill -9`. But they're equivalent on x86, so feel free to use it there if you like.)

If you know there are no other processes with the same name as the one you want to kill, you can use [`killall`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/killall.1.html) instead of `kill` and the name of the process instead of the process ID number.

### A Process Monopolizing CPU Resources

If a process runs at or very near the highest possible priority (or to state it more properly, at or near the lowest possible [niceness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix))), it could potentially render your graphical user interface completely, or near-completely, unresponsive. However, in this situation, you would likely not be able to switch to a virtual console and run commands (or maybe even reboot).

If a process or a combination of processes running at normal or moderately elevated priority are slowing your machine down, you should be able to kill them using the technique in the section above. But if they are graphical programs, you can likely also kill them by clicking the close button on their windows--the desktop environment will give you the option to kill them if they are not responding. If this doesn't work, of course you can (almost) always kill them with `kill -KILL`.

### I/O Problems

Buggy [I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output) can cause prolonged (even perpetual) unresponsiveness. This can be due to a kernel bug and/or buggy drivers. A partial workaround is to avoid heavy and simultaneous read and/or write operations (for example, don't copy two big files at once, in two simultaneous copy processes; don't copy a big file while watching an HD video or installing an OS in a virtual machine).

This is obviously unsatisfactory and the real solution is to find the problem and report it. Unless you're running a mainline kernel from [kernel.org](https://kernel.org), kernel bugs should be reported against the package `linux` in Ubuntu (since Ubuntu gives special kernel builds that integrate distro-specific patches, and bug reports not confirmed against a mainline kernel will be rejected at [kernel.org](https://kernel.org)). You should do this by running `ubuntu-bug linux` (or `apport-cli linux`) on the affected machine. See the [Ubuntu bug reporting documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) first; it explains how to do this properly.

### Graphics Card Problems

Some GUI lockups can be caused by graphics card problems. There are a few things you can try, to alleviate this:

1. Search the web to see if other people have experienced similar problems with the same video card (and/or make and model of machine) on Ubuntu or other GNU/Linux distributions. There may be solutions more specific than what I can offer in this answer, without more specific information than is currently in your question.
2. See if different video drivers are available for you to try. You can do this by checking in Additional Drivers; you can also search the web to see what Linux drivers are available for your video card. Most proprietary video cards are Intel, [AMD/ATi](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI), or [Nvidia](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) (click those links to see the community documentation on installing and using proprietary drivers for these cards in Ubuntu). For Intel, you're best off sticking with the FOSS drivers that are present in Ubuntu, but there's still [helpful information](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsIntel) you can use. Regardless of what card you have, [this general information](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Video) may help.

   If you're currently using proprietary drivers, you can try using different proprietary drivers (for example, directly from NVidia or AMD/ATi), or you can try using the free open source drivers instead.
3. Try selecting a graphical login **session type** that doesn't require/use graphics acceleration. To do this, log out, and on the graphical login screen click the Ubuntu logo or gear icon near your login name. A drop-down menu is shown. Change the selection from *Ubuntu* to *Ubuntu 2D*. This makes you use [Unity 2D](https://launchpad.net/unity-2d) instead of [Unity](https://unity.ubuntu.com/). (If you're using [GNOME Shell](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell), you can select [*GNOME Fallback*](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gnome-3-fallback.html) / *GNOME Classic* instead.) If in doubt and there's a selection that says "no effects," pick that, as that's probably the safest.

   [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83351/which-is-correct-gnome-classic-or-gnome-fallback) has some more information about different graphical interfaces you can choose between in Ubuntu.
4. In newer versions of Ubuntu, you can choose between X.org and Wayland on the login screen. Whichever you've been using, try the other. Sometimes a problem with Wayland can be fixed by using X.org, or vice versa.
5. [Report a bug.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

*Hopefully the information above has conveyed some general information about what could be causing this kind of problem. It should also serve to illuminate what kind of information might be useful for you to add to your question (depending on the specific details of the problem), to make it possible to get an even better answer. (Or to improve this answer with additional information specific to your situation.)*

Comment: Nicely well-done tips to troubleshoot hangs.

Comment: If the keyboard stops responding it's not possible to use Ctrl+Alt+FN

Comment: In my case, it becomes completely unresponsive. Even numluck or capslock keyboard light doesn't toggle. None of the above works. Only option is to press reboot. Ubuntu 20.04 fully updated.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the easiest way to archieve this, is enable the keys to kill Xorg server, and re-launch X session.

To enable this, open System Settings -> Keyboard Layout options (or use 
`keyboard` command in Unity interface, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>), and check this option:

> Ctrl + Alt + Backspace

[image]

So when it hangs, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> will kill X server, and lightdm will re-launch login interface

Comment: `Alt+Print+K` will do the same out of the box, no?

Comment: How to do this in Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Comment: @Bobby Thanks for pointing that out; Ctrl+Alt+Bksp does not respond, but Alt+PrtSc+K works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem before, it was because I have missed up with some gnome shell extensions.

I simply did a factory reset to reset settings and remove all tweaks hence, everything worked pretty well.

In the terminal just write those two commands:

```
dconf reset -f /
dconf dump /
```

If you can't use any shortcuts and can't open the terminal (just like my case) , you can open it from the boot menu:

-In the boot menu choose advanced options

-Choose recovery mode

-Select network

-Type the user name and the password

-Type the following commands:

```
dconf reset -f /
dconf dump /
```

This will remove all the tweaks and custom settings